# Function callback from C to Swift

Tags: c, swift

I have this C function that simply calls back another function passed as a parameter

```
void call_my_function(void (*callback_function)())
{
    callback_function();
}
```

This is C test code:

```
void func_to_call()    // a simple test function passed in as a callback
{
    printf("function correctly called");
}

void test()   // entry point
{
    void (*foo)();
    foo = &func_to_call;
    call_my_function(foo);     // pass the address of "func_to_call()" to "call_my_function()"
}
```

Essentially, from `test()`, I call `call_my_function()` passing in the address of `func_to_call()`, and then `call_my_function()` calls back `func_to_call()`.

From swift I see correctly the functions `test()` and `func_to_call()`, but it seems that

```
void call_my_function(void (*callback_function)())
```

is not recognized (use of unresolved identifier)
If I remove the parameter `void (*callback_function)()` then the function is recognized again.

What can I do to pass a Swift function address to C and have it called back? Is it possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple confirmed me, on the dev forum, that it is not supported now, and requested me to fill a new request on the bugreporter.

Moreover, I give to the readers another detail:

It seems that in the compiled binary the symbols for all swift functions are already available and bridged to be accessible from C (even in a swift-only app)

I made an app called FunctionTest, iPhone App with this function in a swift file

func thisIsATestFunction()
{
    println("test")
}

compiled, and then from Terminal:

nc /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FunctionTest-hhrbtzsuyrdoftfnbakosvenaiak/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FunctionTest.app/FunctionTest

```
     U _NSStringFromClass
     U _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSString
     U _OBJC_CLASS_$_UIResponder
     U _OBJC_CLASS_$_UIViewController
     U _OBJC_CLASS_$_UIWindow
000088c8 S _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC12FunctionTest11AppDelegate
00008888 S _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC12FunctionTest14ViewController
.........
.........
00003840 T __TF12FunctionTest19thisIsATestFunctionFT_T_          <--- this is my test function
```

Calling from c the address 00003840 executed the function

```
void (* func)() = 0x00003840;
func();    // the swift function is executed
```

So I think that this is already work-in-progress...hoping that they will implement this functionality in the next releases :-)

Comment: And? Is there a way to get C function pointers from swift closures now?

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/a/30788165/5512384, as it solves this problem in a safer way.