# Create MTAudioProcessingTapCallbacks in Swift 2

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2, mediatoolbox

I've been banging my head on the wall for hours trying to create a `MTAudioProcessingTapCallbacks` from the `MediaToolbox` library, using Swift 2. **I found [this great article](http://venodesigns.net/2014/01/08/recording-live-audio-streams-on-ios/) with an implementation in Objective-C,** so I thought I would try to re-write it in Swift, so that I can understand it better, however that is proving a bit beyond me at the moment.

The main issue is that I can't find a way to cast the return value of `MTAudioProcessingTapGetStorage(tap)` (which is an `UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>`) to an `RMStreamer`, which appears to be a feature of the original implementation:

```
RMStreamer *streamer = (__bridge RMStreamer *) MTAudioProcessingTapGetStorage(tap);
```

If I attempt this in the most obvious way:

```
var streamer = MTAudioProcessingTapGetStorage(tap) as! RMStreamer
```

I get a warning saying:

> Cast from UnsafeMutablePointer (aka 'UnsafeMutablePointer<()> to unrelated type RMStreamer always fails)"

So, I found out that the `__bridge` is somehow equivalent to `takeUnretainedValue()` but that method does not seem to be available anywhere in this context. I suspect I'm being rather ignorant, but does anyone know if it is possible to implement this kind of thing in Swift 2, or am I better off just learning Objective-C and using that for `MediaToolbox` stuff in future?

Comment: Hey Sam! How did you manage to create the actual tap callbacks? I'm stuck at that point... for example     `var callbacks: MTAudioProcessingTapCallbacks ... callbacks.prepare = ???`

Answer (score 2):

Well, I eventually figured out how to get this little piece of the puzzle compiling (I still haven't tested it at runtime), using:

```
let streamer = Unmanaged<RMStreamer>.fromOpaque(COpaquePointer(MTAudioProcessingTapGetStorage(tap))).takeUnretainedValue()
```

All I found this out from from https://stackoverflow.com/a/30788165/73237

**UPDATE** To make this a bit easier to use, wrote the following swift class, mimicking the obj-c nomenclature..

```swift
class __bridge<T:AnyObject> {
    class func from(p: UnsafeMutablePointer<()>) -> T {
        return Unmanaged<T>.fromOpaque(COpaquePointer(p)).takeUnretainedValue()
    }
}
```

Which can be invoked like this, for example:

```
let streamer = __bridge<RMStreamer>.from(MTAudioProcessingTapGetStorage(tap))
```