# How to use instance method as callback for function which takes only func or literal closure

Tags: swift, callback

In "ViewController.swift" I am creating this callback:

```
func callback(cf:CFNotificationCenter!, 
    ump:UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>, 
    cfs:CFString!, 
    up:UnsafePointer<Void>, 
    cfd:CFDictionary!) -> Void {

}
```

Using this observer:

```
CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter(), 
    nil, 
    self.callback, 
    "myMESSage", 
    nil, 
    CFNotificationSuspensionBehavior.DeliverImmediately)
```

Results in this compiler error:

> "A C function pointer can only be formed from a reference to a 'func' or a literal closure"

Comment: Hi, did you ever solve it?

Comment: @elect you just need to move it out of your view controller class. It needs to be global

Answer (score 56):

The callback is a pointer to a C function, and in Swift you can pass
only a global function or a closure (which does not capture any state),
but not an instance method.

So this does work:

```
CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter(),
        nil,
        { (_, observer, name, _, _) in
            print("received notification: \(name)")
        },
        "myMessage",
        nil,
        .DeliverImmediately)
```

But since the closure cannot capture context, you have no direct reference to `self` and its properties and instance methods.
For example, you cannot add

```
self.label.stringValue = "got it"
// error: a C function pointer cannot be formed from a closure that captures context
```

inside the closure to update the UI when a notification arrived.

There is a solution, but it is a little bit complicated due to
Swift's strict type system.
Similarly as in [Swift 2 - UnsafeMutablePointer<Void> to object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30786883/swift-2-unsafemutablepointervoid-to-object), you can convert the pointer to
`self` to a void pointer, pass that as the `observer` parameter 
to the registration, and convert it back to an object pointer in
the callback.

```
class YourClass { 

    func callback(name : String) {
        print("received notification: \(name)")
    }

    func registerObserver() {

        // Void pointer to `self`:
        let observer = UnsafePointer<Void>(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque())

        CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter(),
            observer,
            { (_, observer, name, _, _) -> Void in

                // Extract pointer to `self` from void pointer:
                let mySelf = Unmanaged<YourClass>.fromOpaque(
                        COpaquePointer(observer)).takeUnretainedValue()
                // Call instance method:
                mySelf.callback(name as String)
            },
            "myMessage",
            nil,
            .DeliverImmediately)
    }

    // ...
}
```

The closure acts as a "trampoline" to the instance method.

The pointer is an unretained reference, therefore you must ensure
that the observer is removed before the object is deallocated.

---

**Update for Swift 3:**

```
class YourClass {

    func callback(_ name : String) {
        print("received notification: \(name)")
    }

    func registerObserver() {

        // Void pointer to `self`:
        let observer = UnsafeRawPointer(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque())

        CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter(),
            observer,
            { (_, observer, name, _, _) -> Void in
                if let observer = observer, let name = name {

                    // Extract pointer to `self` from void pointer:
                    let mySelf = Unmanaged<YourClass>.fromOpaque(observer).takeUnretainedValue()
                    // Call instance method:
                    mySelf.callback(name.rawValue as String)
                }
            },
            "myMessage" as CFString,
            nil,
            .deliverImmediately)
    }

    // ...
}
```

---

See also [How to cast self to UnsafeMutablePointer<Void> type in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33294620/how-to-cast-self-to-unsafemutablepointervoid-type-in-swift) for more information
about the "bridging" between object pointers and C pointers.

Comment: I've used your approach but still get error (" A C function pointer cannot be formed from a closure that captures context "). But when trying to call an instance method using mySelf, Xcode doesn't complain, it sees the method.

Comment: Hi @MartinR, Thanks for the solution. But i think the statement in your answer "closure cannot capture context" is not valid. Closure can capture context but function poster or c function cannot. Please let me know if I misunderstood something.

Comment: @SauravNagpal: Only a global function or a closure which does not capture context can be passed to a C function as a function pointer argument. That's what I tried to express in the first sentence.

Comment: If you need this solution for CFNotificationCenterGetDistributedCenter and target OS X 10.10 or above, you can also use NSDistributedNotificationCenter instead, which lets you pass a selector and has a nicer API.

Comment: You just marked my question as a duplicate of this, but our requirements are totally different. Should the question have the answer for the ops requirement? Can you add your comments on my answer with the solution?

Comment: @Hemang: It is exactly the same problem (you cannot use "self" in the closure) and exactly the same solution: You have to convert self to a void pointer, pass that as context pointer to the callback (in your case using the last argument of CGPDFScannerCreate), and convert back to an instance pointer in the callback. – Here is another example of the same technique: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30788165/1187415.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the function I wanted to call from my closure was in the AppDelegate.  So I was able to use a delegate to call the function from the closure without using self.  Whether this is a *good* idea or not is something that someone with more experience will have to comment on.

```
        self.pingSocket = CFSocketCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_ICMP,CFSocketCallBackType.dataCallBack.rawValue, {socket, type, address, data, info in
            //type is CFSocketCallBackType
            guard let socket = socket, let address = address, let data = data, let info = info else { return }

// stuff deleted, including use of C pointers

            let appDelegate = NSApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
            appDelegate.receivedPing(ip: sourceIP, sequence: sequence, id: id)
            //}
            return
        }, &context)

extension AppDelegate: ReceivedPingDelegate {
    func receivedPing(ip: UInt32, sequence: UInt16, id: UInt16) {
        // stuff deleted
    }
}
protocol ReceivedPingDelegate: class {
    func receivedPing(ip: UInt32, sequence: UInt16, id: UInt16)
}
```

Comment: Doesn’t work for me (Swift 5, Xcode 10.2): `A C function pointer cannot be formed from a local function that captures context`