# A C function pointer cannot be formed from a local function that captures context

Tags: objective-c, swift

I get the following error for the code below: "A C function pointer cannot be formed from a local function that captures context."

Does anyone propose a creative solution to populate `x` in this example? I'm stumped. The underlying types for `_header` and `_int` respectively are `UnsafePointer<mach_header>?` and `Int`

```
import MachO
class Example {
    func test() {
        var x: [Int] = []
        _dyld_register_func_for_add_image { (_header, _int) in
            x.append(_int)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That code compiles without problems for me.

Comment: How about in the case `x` is not a static variable?

Comment: That wouldn't work. `_dyld_register_func_for_add_image` takes a C function as argument. In Swift that are global functions or closure that capture no context.  *If* there were a user pointer parameter then you could use a technique as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/33262376/1187415, but such a parameter is not available here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make `x` a static variable so it is accessible from anywhere and not depending on context. But it depends on your use case whether this works.