# A C function pointer cannot be formed from a closure that captures context

Tags: ios, swift

The question is different because I want to take out *info* value out of the closure. And right now, it's empty thus I couldn't call any outside function. This is what I have tried so far:

```
CGPDFOperatorTableSetCallback(operatorTableRef!, "BT") { (scanner, info) in
    if let info = info {
        let myObject = Unmanaged<ViewController>.fromOpaque(info).takeUnretainedValue()
        myObject.printinfo(info: info as AnyObject)
}
    }

func printinfo(info:AnyObject) -> Void {
    print("Printing:\n\(info)")
    print("------------------------------------------------------------")
}
```

---

I am playing with a PDF to extract strings from it. There's one call block that I should implement. All well, except I can't call any outside function or can't use any variable within that block.

```
    CGPDFOperatorTableSetCallback(operatorTableRef!, "BT") { (scanner, info) in
        //I can't do anything here except this:
        print("Yes, I can print.")
        //hello() //or self.hello() //all cries.
}

func hello()->Void {
    //hello.
}
```

Comment: This *is* a duplicate of [How to use instance method as callback for function which takes only func or literal closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33260808/how-to-use-instance-method-as-callback-for-function-which-takes-only-func-or-lit), even if you reopened it: Same error message ("A C function pointer cannot be formed from a closure that captures context"), same problem (you cannot use "self" in the closure which is used as C callback), same solution (bridge "self" to void pointer and back).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use instance method as callback for function which takes only func or literal closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33260808/how-to-use-instance-method-as-callback-for-function-which-takes-only-func-or-lit)

Comment: @Larme, yes it can be but my case it different, as you can see in the updated question.

Comment: @Hemang: What does not work with your updated code? How do you call CGPDFScannerCreate?

Comment: @MartinR, here I want to confirm: I am able to get a call inside the closure but then `if let info = info {...}` condition never matches.

Comment: @Hemang: You have to pass "self" (converted to a UnsafeMutableRawPointer) to CGPDFScannerCreate (as in the answer that I linked to).

Comment: I am not understanding what you mean, could you please add your answer here?

Comment: You do `let scanner = CGPDFScannerCreate(stream, operatorTableRef, nil)`, right? Ask you this: WHY do you write "nil" in the third parameter? What's the name of that parameter in the declaration of that method? If you put (a valid) let's call it `MyCustomValidVard, then `CGPDFOperatorTableSetCallback(operatorTableRef!, "BT") { (scanner, info) in` `info` will be `MyCustomValidVard`. So if you give `self` using the linked answer, you'll be able to use `self` in that closure.