# how implement callback from C++ function to Swift

Tags: c++, ios, swift, callback

I tried do something in a cpp class and when doing the function return callback to swift.

So i do these things :

1. Creating this function in `callbackClass.cpp`

   ```
   int callback::run(void (*callback)(int))
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            callback(i);
        }
        return 0;
    }
   ```
2. In `callbackClass.hpp` :

   ```
   class callbackClass.hpp
   {
     .
     .
     .
     public:
        int run(void (*callback)(int));
   };

   #endif
   ```
3. And for `header.h‍‍` :

   ```
   int callback(void (*callback)(int));
   ```

It's good until logging callback in `Swift` side:

```
func callbackFunc(){

  callback({valueFromCallback in //call cpp function

    print(valueFromCallback) //Works fine

  })
}
```

But when try to do other stuff like :

```
func callbackFunc(){

  var value : String!

  callback({valueFromCallback in //call cpp function

    value = String(valueFromCallback) //It has a problem

  })
}
```

Xcode return this error :

> A C function pointer cannot be formed from a closure that captures context

I have already seen these questions but did not help:

[Swift: Pass data to a closure that captures context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33551191/swift-pass-data-to-a-closure-that-captures-context)

[How to cast self to UnsafeMutablePointer<Void> type in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33294620/how-to-cast-self-to-unsafemutablepointervoid-type-in-swift)

[A C function pointer cannot be formed from a closure that captures context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44261460/a-c-function-pointer-cannot-be-formed-from-a-closure-that-captures-context)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually I realized it possible to pass 'closure' to c++ as argument

So at first I created a Closure in Swift class:

```
typealias closureCallback = (Int32) -> ()
```

Then passed it to cpp side :

1. In `header.h‍‍`

   ```
   int callback(void (^closureCallback)(int));
   ```
2. In `callbackClass.hpp` :

   ```
   class callbackClass.hpp
   {
     .
     .
     .

     public:
         int run(void (^closureCallback)(int));
   };

   #endif
   ```
3. And in `callbackClass.cpp`

   ```
   int callback::run(void (^closureCallback)(int))
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            closureCallback(i);
        }
        return 0;
    }
   ```

At last handle it in Swift :

```
typealias closureCallback = (Int32) -> ()

func callbackFunc(){

  var value : String!

  let closureValue: closureCallback = {valueFromclosureCallback in
      value = String(valueFromclosureCallback)
   }

    callback(closureValue) //call cpp function

}
```

Comment: This solved a problem I've been struggling with for a few days and it's surprisingly straight-forward. Thank you!

Comment: @DavidSpry Yw, If you find a answer correct, you can vote for the answer instead of thanking it