# how to call a function that takes a function pointer argument in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, pointers, function-pointers

According to Apple Documentation:

> When calling a function that takes a function pointer argument, you can pass a top-level Swift function, a closure literal, or nil.

I've tried this example from Apple Documentation: [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-ID17)

```
func customCopyDescription(_ p: UnsafeRawPointer?) -> Unmanaged<CFString>? {
    // return an Unmanaged<CFString>? value
}

var callbacks = CFArrayCallBacks(
    version: 0,
    retain: nil,
    release: nil,
    copyDescription: customCopyDescription,
    equal: { (p1, p2) -> DarwinBoolean in
        // return Bool value
}
)
```

but I got an error message in Xcode: (copyDescription: customCopyDescription error)

> *A C function pointer can only be formed from a reference to a 'func' or a literal closure*

As mentioned at apple documentation , customCopyDescription can be passed as a top-level swift function, but it's seems like something is wrong in the documentation.

How to pass the customCopyDescription func to the CFArrayCallBacks as a swift function(*not a closure literal*)?

Comment: Did you put that inside a class definition? `customCopyDescription` needs to be a *global function.* – See also [How to use instance method as callback for function which takes only func or literal closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33260808/how-to-use-instance-method-as-callback-for-function-which-takes-only-func-or-lit).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`customCopyDescription` needs to be a *free* function, not a method. When I copied your code into Xcode I got the error message only when `customCopyDescription` was inside a class, not otherwise.

Once placeholder return values are added and `customCopyDescription` is placed at file scope, the code compiles without a problem