# Swift can't call self from c callback in linphone sdk

Tags: c, swift, callback, linphone, linphone-sdk

I have problem when try to call Swift instance method from c callback.

**Error:** "A C function pointer cannot be formed from a closure that captures context."

```
linphone_core_cbs_set_registration_state_changed(cbs) { (lc, cfg, state, message) in            
        switch state{ 
          case LinphoneRegistrationOk:
            print("LinphoneRegistrationOk")        
            self.call()        
        }

func call() {        
    let account = "test"
    let domain = "sip.linphone.org"
    let identity = "sip:" + account + "@" + domain
    linphone_core_invite(lc, identity)
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use instance method as callback for function which takes only func or literal closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33260808/how-to-use-instance-method-as-callback-for-function-which-takes-only-func-or-lit)

Answer (score 1):

If you have the ability to pass an arbitrary `void*` as a context then using `Unmanaged<SelfType>.passUnretained(self).toOpaque()` and converting it back with `Unmanaged<SelfType>.fromOpaque(context).takeUnretainedValue()` is the best solution.

But based on your small snippet of `(lc, cfg, state, message)` none of them seem like a context pointer. So getting self back is still possible but likely more complex. Because you will need to create a global/static piece of data that can be accessed from inside your closure in a safe manner. Some ideas of how you can do this are below:

1) You can do this with just a simple global/static if you know that is safe.

2) You can use thread local storage and store a pointer to `self` and cast it back and forth in the same way as if you had the `void*` argument and used `Unmanaged`. This one of course requires that your C callback be raised on the same thread where you store the value.

3) If you have access to a unique identifier that both Swift and C can access that will continue to be valid and accessible in your callback you can create a map of type `[UniqueIdentifierAccessibleBySwiftAndC: TypeOfSelf]` and use that to get `self` back.

Comment: Thanks you solution was hepful