# Wrapping C callbacks (without context) into Swift Closures

Tags: c, swift, callback, closures, function-pointers

I'm trying to lear Swift by playing around with a wrapper to GLFW

GLFW allows to add error callbacks with:

`GLFWAPI GLFWerrorfun glfwSetErrorCallback(GLFWerrorfun cbfun);`

where

`typedef void (* GLFWerrorfun)(int,const char*);`

I tried googling but many solutions refers to callbacks expecting a final parameter which represents the context.

Context parameter which unfortunately I don't have it here.

This is what [seems it should work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33262376/1047713) (although the OP explicitly asked for a case similar to mine, no context parameter):

```
class glfw {
   typealias ErrorFun = (Int, _ description: String) -> Void
   func setErrorCallback(cbFun: ErrorFun) {
        // Void pointer to `self`:
        let observer = UnsafeRawPointer(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque())

        glfwSetErrorCallback { err, desc in

            // Extract pointer to `self` from void pointer:
            let mySelf = Unmanaged<glfw>.fromOpaque(observer).takeUnretainedValue()
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

But it keeps firing:

> error: a C function pointer cannot be formed from a closure that captures context

as soon as I try to use `observer` in the callback, context seems captured

How may I solve?

Comment: Do you know which thread the callback takes place on? Is it the same one that is calling the original function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using a global variable

```
public struct glfw {
    static func setErrorCallback(cbFun: @escaping ErrorFun) {
        _g.errorCB = cbFun
        glfwSetErrorCallback { err, desc in
            _g.errorCB!(Error(rawValue: err)!, String(utf8String: desc!)!)
        }        
    }
    var errorCB: ErrorFun?
}
var _g = glfw()
```