# swift @objc and selector : compiler error with type returned from selector

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, libvlc, vlckit

on MacOS 10.14.6, Swift and XCode 11.0, VLCKit 3.3.0,
I try to create callbacks with @objc functions, within a class.
But using #selector to point to my @objc func, the compiler generates an error

these are the 2 functions I declare within my class

```
class VLCStreamProcessor {
// ...

@objc func lock_frame(
    opaque: UnsafeMutableRawPointer? ,
    planes: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutableRawPointer?>?)
    -> UnsafeMutableRawPointer? 
{ // ...
    return UnsafeMutableRawPointer(user_data.pic)
}

@objc func unlock_frame(
    opaque: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?,
    picture: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?,
    planes: UnsafePointer<UnsafeMutableRawPointer?>?)
{ // ...
}
```

then in an other function (myVLCProcessing), still within same class, I prepare my call backs

```
func myVLCProcessing() 
{ // ...

  libvlc_video_set_callbacks( 
    mplayerPtr, // type libvlc_media_player_t*
    #selector( lock_frame(opaque:planes:) ), // type libvlc_video_lock_cb <- 1st error
    #selector( unlock_frame(opaque:picture:planes: )), // type libvlc_video_unlock_cb <- 2nd error
    0,  // type libvlc_video_display_cb
    opaque // type void*
    ) 

  // ...
}
```

there I get a compiler error, on the 2 lines with #selector :
first :

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Selector' to expected argument type 'libvlc_video_lock_cb?' (aka 'Optional<@convention(c)(Optional<UnsafeMutableRawPointer>, Optional<UnsafeMutablePointer<Optional<UnsafeMutableRawPointer>>>) -> Optional<UnsafeMutableRawPointer>>')
```

second:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Selector' to specified type 'libvlc_video_unlock_cb' (aka '@convention(c) (Optional<UnsafeMutableRawPointer>, Optional<UnsafeMutableRawPointer>, Optional<UnsafePointer<Optional<UnsafeMutableRawPointer>>>) -> ()')
```

from the libvlc (libvlc_media_player.h), the 2 C-functions are expected as :

```
typedef void *(*libvlc_video_lock_cb)(void *opaque, void **planes);

typedef void (*libvlc_video_unlock_cb)(void *opaque, void *picture,
                                   void *const *planes);
```

any advice welcome.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33262376/1187415

Comment: helpful : this describes the situation I face - but path to solution is not clear yet - trying to understand what I do wrong in the notion of " can only be formed from a reference to a 'func'"  - in parallel, I'm testing re-write of my code  as literal closures (not easy to read/debug afterwards)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only global functions or closures (which capture no context) can be passed to the C function for the callback arguments. Similarly as in [How to use instance method as callback for function which takes only func or literal closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33260808/how-to-use-instance-method-as-callback-for-function-which-takes-only-func-or-lit/33262376#33262376) you can “tunnel” `self` (the pointer to the instance) to the callback functions by converting it to a `void` pointer and back. The callback function can then call the instance method:

```
class VLCStreamProcessor {
    func lock_frame(
        planes: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutableRawPointer?>?)
        -> UnsafeMutableRawPointer?
    { // ...
    }

    func unlock_frame(
        picture: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?,
        planes: UnsafePointer<UnsafeMutableRawPointer?>?)
    { // ...
    }

    func myVLCProcessing()  {
        // ...

        let opaque = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque())
        libvlc_video_set_callbacks(mplayerPtr, { (opaque, planes) -> UnsafeMutableRawPointer? in
            let mySelf = Unmanaged<VLCStreamProcessor>.fromOpaque(opaque!).takeUnretainedValue()
            return mySelf.lock_frame(planes: planes)
        }, { (opaque, picture, planes) in
            let mySelf = Unmanaged<VLCStreamProcessor>.fromOpaque(opaque!).takeUnretainedValue()
            mySelf.unlock_frame(picture: picture, planes: planes)
        }, nil, opaque)

    }
}
```

Here it is assumed that the `VLCStreamProcessor` exists as long as the libvlc callbacks are set, otherwise the pointers have to be retained.

Comment: Thx Martin : your solution compiles OK. Still some work to do before I go thru runtime tests.

Answer (score 0):

A selector is not the same as a C-function. You need to supply a closure or a function pointer instead.

Just try to remove the #selector() around the functions you supply.

Comment: doing this generates the following error "A C function pointer can only be formed from a reference to a 'func' or a literal closure"