# Swift: A C function pointer cannot be formed from a closure that captures conte

Tags: c++, ios, c, swift, ffi

I want to call the callback function from native code:

From header:

```
void load_all(Client *client,
                         void (*cb_result)(const ResponseWrapper*),
                         void (*cb_error)(char*));
```

This is my callback in Swift:

```
 let result: @convention(c) (UnsafePointer<ResponseWrapper>?) -> Void = { pointer in
      if let ResponseWrapper = pointer?.pointee {
        print("data \(data.length)")
      }
    }
```

When I try to return results from `result` callback  to swift I got next error:

```
A C function pointer cannot be formed from a closure that captures context
```

**What is the best way to overcome this limitation?**

*Is the only way to save an instance of my class to a pointer, send to native code and cast back to object?*

```
let owner = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(Unmanaged.passRetained(callbackWrapper).toOpaque())
let owner: Response = Unmanaged.fromOpaque($0!).takeUnretainedValue()
```

*This is not working as well:*

```
func loadAll() {

    //Loader class
    let ownedPointer = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque())

    let result: @convention(c) (UnsafePointer<ResponseWrapper>?) -> Void = { pointer in
      if let ResponseWrapper = pointer?.pointee {
        print("data \(data.length)")
      }
      let newSelf:Loader = Unmanaged.fromOpaque(ownedPointer).takeUnretainedValue()
    }
}
```

**My current solution:**

- **Swift** : gist.github.com/xajik/fe360b705f63ceba4a71f94d1ce2dc41
- **Rust**: gist.github.com/xajik/8b532c44e3a267a5d8ae450ea11ad41c

Comment: Did you have a look at [How to use instance method as callback for function which takes only func or literal closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33260808/how-to-use-instance-method-as-callback-for-function-which-takes-only-func-or-lit) ?

Comment: *"Is the only way to save an instance of my class to a pointer, send to native code and cast back to object?"* – Yes.

Comment: What if it, not my library and I cannot modify it? There is no way to get data?

Comment: But you have to take care of the reference counting. With `passRetained()` you keep the instance alive, but must release it eventually to avoid a memory leak. With `passUnretained()` you must ensure that the instance is alive as long as the callback is active.

Comment: Understood. 
So if I cannot modify the source code of the library I can not to anything here?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you mean. All the pointer juggling is done on the Swift side, not in the C library.

Comment: I added one more example, please check

Comment: How does it “not work”? What is ResponseWrapper? Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Here `self ` and `ResponseWrapper ` are different object. Based on the link you shared first I need to send `self` to native code and return to the callback with `ResponseWrapper` - I managed to make it work like that.
So my questions is there any possible hack to avoid this?

Comment: I created a gist to explain it better: 
Swift : https://gist.github.com/xajik/fe360b705f63ceba4a71f94d1ce2dc41
Rust: https://gist.github.com/xajik/8b532c44e3a267a5d8ae450ea11ad41c