# Pass an UnsafeMutableRawPointer as a function parameter

Tags: swift

When I try to pass an UnsafeMutableRawPointer as a function parameter I get the following error:

`A C function pointer can only be formed from a reference to a 'func' or a literal closure`

Specifically this is from the following code:

```
public func sqlite3_bind_text(_ oP: OpaquePointer!, _ first: Int32, _ second: UnsafePointer<Int8>!, _ third: Int32, _ ptrs: ((UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) -> Void)!) -> Int32 {
    SQLite3.sqlite3_bind_text(oP, first, second, third, ptrs)
}
```

I've looked at: [How to use instance method as callback for function which takes only func or literal closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33260808/how-to-use-instance-method-as-callback-for-function-which-takes-only-func-or-lit) but can't see how I can apply that to my situation.

How can I pass the pointer through my function?

Comment: Provide signature of `SQLite3.sqlite3_bind_text(...)`

Comment: func sqlite3_bind_text(_: OpaquePointer!, _: Int32, _: UnsafePointer<Int8>!, _: Int32, _: ((UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) -> Void)!) -> Int32

Comment: You have  to add “@convention(c)” to the parameter declaration of your wrapper function as well: `_ ptrs: (@convention(c) (UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) -> Void)!` – But what is the point of defining a function with the same signature  as `SQLite3.sqlite3_bind_text` and forwarding the call?

Comment: Dependency injection, want to swap out the implementation

Comment: Note that the last parameter is not a UnsafeMutableRawPointer but a pointer to a function (which takes a UnsafeMutableRawPointer parameter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite is a pure C library, and `SQLite3.sqlite3_bind_text()` takes a pointer to a C function as the fifth parameter. Such a parameter is marked with `@convention(c)` and that must be replicated in your wrapper function:

```
public func sqlite3_bind_text(_ oP: OpaquePointer!, _ first: Int32,
                              _ second: UnsafePointer<Int8>!,
                              _ third: Int32,
                              _ ptrs: (@convention(c) (UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) -> Void)!) -> Int32 {
    SQLite3.sqlite3_bind_text(oP, first, second, third, ptrs)
}
```