# Using @convention(c) to deal with c callback function in Swift 2

Tags: swift2

Why? Always crash, when i using unsafeBitCast function, please refer to following code and an error message:

Code: "let obj: MyController = unsafeBitCast(context, MyController.self)"

```
Error: Thread11: EXEC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x20)

public class MyController: NSObject {

    public override init() {
        super.init()
        registerEventHandler()
    }

    let callback: @convention(c) (Int ,UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) -> Void = { event, context in

        //Always crash, when i deal with context using unsafeBitCast
        let obj: MyController = unsafeBitCast(context, MyController.self)
    }

    public func registerEventHandler() {
        let selfObj = unsafeBitCast(self, UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>.self)

        //call C function
        RegisterEventHandler(callback, selfObj)
    }
}
```

Comment: hm ... is hard to see, what actually happened in your code, but your idea should work.class C {
    var i = 1
    func foo() { print("foo") }
}

let c = C()
c.i = 10
// this cast class C as UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>
let c1 = unsafeBitCast(c, UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>.self)
// this cast UnsafeMutablePointer<Void> as C
let c2: C = unsafeBitCast(c1, C.self)
c2.foo()
c2.i // 10

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30786883/swift-2-unsafemutablepointervoid-to-object for a similar issue. – Is it guaranteed that `MyController` won't get deallocated while the callback is still registered?