# Swift2, Call swift function in CFSocketCallBack - EXEC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: swift, pointers, callback, swift2, cfsocket

I'm trying to write a socket server app for Mac OSX with Xcode:7.2.1 in Swift2.1.1. referring to [CocoaEcho sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/CocoaEcho/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003603-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2).
But I cannot call a swift function in the socketCallBack function.
My code is here. I'm passing the self based on the answer at [Swift 2 - UnsafeMutablePointer to object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30786883/swift-2-unsafemutablepointervoid-to-object). And I think the part of the code is working ok.

```
class myServer: NSObject {

  // sockets
  private var socketipv4: CFSocket!
  private var socketipv6: CFSocket!

  // Connections
  var connections = Set<SPFConnection>()

  func start(address: String) -> Bool {

    var sockCtxt = CFSocketContext(version: 0, info: nil, retain: nil, release: nil, copyDescription: nil)
    sockCtxt.info = UnsafeMutablePointer(unsafeAddressOf(self))

    // create socket with CFSocketCreate
    socketipv4 = CFSocketCreate(
        kCFAllocatorDefault,
        PF_INET,
        SOCK_STREAM,
        IPPROTO_TCP,
        kCFSocketAutomaticallyReenableAcceptCallBack,
        socketCallBack,
        &sockCtxt)

    // ipv4
    var sin = sockaddr_in()  // = initStruct()
    let server_addr_size = socklen_t(INET_ADDRSTRLEN)
    sin.sin_len = UInt8(server_addr_size)
    sin.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)
    sin.sin_port = UInt16(9999).bigEndian
    sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(address)

    let sinData = NSData(bytes: &sin, length: sizeof(sockaddr_in))
    let ptr = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(sinData.bytes)

    let sincfd = CFDataCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, ptr, sizeof(sockaddr_in))

    let ipv4SocketError: CFSocketError = CFSocketSetAddress(socketipv4, sincfd)
    switch ipv4SocketError {
    case .Success:
        print("ipv4 Success")
    default:
        print("ipv4 error = \(ipv4SocketError.rawValue)")
        return false
    }

    let socketSource = CFSocketCreateRunLoopSource(kCFAllocatorDefault, socketipv4, 0)
    CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), socketSource, kCFRunLoopDefaultMode)

    return true
  }

  // CFSocket call back
  var socketCallBack : @convention(c)(CFSocket!, CFSocketCallBackType, CFData!, UnsafePointer<Void>, UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) -> Void = {
    (socketRef, callbackType, address, data, info) in

    print("acceptConnection callback-ed") // \(socketRef), \(callbackType), \(address), \(data),\(info)")

    var tempData: CFSocketNativeHandle = 0
    var anNSData:NSData = NSData(bytes: data, length: sizeofValue(data))
    anNSData.getBytes(&tempData, length: sizeof(CFSocketNativeHandle))

    var tempAry = [UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>]()
    tempAry.append(info)
    if callbackType == CFSocketCallBackType.AcceptCallBack {
        let server = unsafeBitCast(info, myServer.self)
        // **** EXEC_BAD_ACCESS, code=2 ***** //
        server.acceptConnection(tempData)
    } else {
        print("callbacktype = \(callbackType.rawValue)")
    }
  }


  func acceptConnection(data: CFSocketNativeHandle) {
    print("acceptConnection called")
    var readStream: Unmanaged<CFReadStream>?
    var writeStream: Unmanaged<CFWriteStream>?

    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocket(kCFAllocatorDefault, data, &readStream, &writeStream)
    if readStream != nil && writeStream != nil {
        CFReadStreamSetProperty(readStream!.takeUnretainedValue(), kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket, kCFBooleanTrue)
        CFWriteStreamSetProperty(writeStream!.takeUnretainedValue(), kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket, kCFBooleanTrue)

        let connection = SPFConnection()
        connection.inputStream = readStream!.takeRetainedValue()
        connection.outputStream = writeStream!.takeRetainedValue()

        if connection.open() {
            connections.insert(connection)
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm getting EXEC_BAD_ACCESS code=2 at the code **server.acceptConnection(tempData)**.
Debugger shows same pointer for both **info** and **server**, which should mean **info(self)** is properly assigned to **server**.
But EXEC_BAD_ACCESS seems to mean self is no longer available.
I'm struggling to find a solution. If anyone could give me any advise,
it'd be very much appreciated.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: My guess  would be that the myServer instance has been *deallocated* before the callback is called. Do you maintain a reference to the server somewhere?

Comment: What would be the possible way to do that? The myServer is called from a view controller without retaining it but the instance created by *let server = myServer()* and *server.start()* is called to call the function. I've tried to use takeRetainValue() but compiler didn't like it, then haven't been managed to retain the instance.

Comment: You can make `server` a property of the view controller (if that persists), or of the application delegate, or perhaps better create a global shared instance ...

Comment: @MartinR Thanks a lot indeed. I now don't get the error. I wish I could think of making the property in the view controller instead of trying to retain the instance somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I'll admit I don't know much about using these lower level C conventions, but since the callback function is part of your class, can't just say self.acceptConnection(tempData)?

Comment: CFSocketCreate() is a C function and takes a C function pointer as the callback argument. In Swift, you can only pass a global function or a closure which does not capture any state (that is what the `@convention(c)` annotation stands for). So there is no `self` in the socketCallBack closure. That's why you have to convert `self` to a void pointer, pass that as info pointer to the callback, and then convert it back.

Comment: Yea as soon as I saved that I realized you probably couldn't. This is kind of interesting to me and I understand the issue now from your answer in the comments above, but I will stick to safe code for now! LOL

Comment: @Dan thanks for your answer. I could avoid the error with the advise from Martin R. I'm curious to what you said as "stick to safe code". As far as I understood, there are only 2 options for an app which needs to listen on a port, CFSocket or POSIX. Do you mean high level API can do, too? If so, I'd like to learn that. Any advise will be appreciated.

Comment: No I was sort of just kidding, I know pure swift isn't built for these lower level functions and so you have to deal with these "unsafe" pointers. I'm just saying I don't have a very good understanding of these things yet so I'm not even going to try! LOL