# Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque() to Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

I have the following error:

[image]

the line of code in the image is this:

```
context.info = UnsafeMutablePointer(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque())
```

I am not sure how to fix this. I did look into this:

https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0017-convert-unmanaged-to-use-unsafepointer.md

but, I am not sure how to properly fix the error.

Any help?

Comment: Please show code, not pictures of code. Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30786883/swift-2-unsafemutablepointervoid-to-object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
context.info = UnsafeMutablePointer(OpaquePointer(bitPattern: Unmanaged.passUnretained(self)))
```

Comment: Do you also have a recipe for achieving the inverse, i.e. extracting `mySelf` from `context.info`, in a similar way?

Answer (score 3):

```
UnsafeMutableRawPointer(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque())
```

works for me