# How to send notifications or delegate callbacks from .c files to swift classes?

Tags: ios, c, swift, pjsip

I am planning to create swift SDK using PJSIP. I have created XCPjsua.h file and XCPjsua.c file. I am interacting with XCPjsua.c file using XCPjsua.h header file and I have below methods

```
int startPjsip(char *sipUser, char* sipDomain);


 /**
* Make VoIP call.
* @param destUri the uri of the receiver, something like "sip:192.168.43.106:5080"; 
*/

    2. void makeCall(char* destUri);

    3. void endCall();
```

From my .swift class I can import XCPjsua.h and I can call startPjsip(), makeCall(), endCall() methods. Is there a way to send delegate callbacks or notifications to swift class from this XCPjsua.c file.

For ex: if I get Incoming call, XCPjsua.c file will receive the incoming call. From XCPjsua.c if I want notify to swift class that "You have received incoming call" how can I do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38334529/2065045 When making the call send a callback, or when initializing register the callback for the events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have control over the code in `XCPjsua.[ch]`, you don't even have to worry about writing a wrapper: you can define the callback type and the function(s) using the callback as you wish, in a "Swifty" way.

Here is a super-simplified example, where the callback is a function that takes no arguments and returns nothing.  A Swift callback is provided to C code as a closure.  You can make it much fancier (and practical/realistic) and if you run into problems, please let people here know.

In `XCPjsua.h`, which you can import into your bridging header:

```
// Callback type
typedef void(*call_received_cb_t)();

// A C function that monitors for incoming calls.  It takes a callback
// as a parameter and will call it when a call comes in.
void monitorIncoming(call_received_cb_t cb);
```

An implementation in `XCPjsua.c`:

```
void monitorIncoming(call_received_cb_t cb) {
    puts("Monitoring for incoming calls...");
    // Received a call!
    cb();
}
```

Finally, here is some Swift code:

```
monitorIncoming({ print("Processing an incoming call in Swift!")})
```