# Bad access to self defined outside the closure

Tags: swift, closures

```
class Sound {

    var soundID: SystemSoundID = 0

    var isPlaying = false

    func playSound() {

        let soundURL = ...
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundURL, &soundID)

        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID)
        self.isPlaying = true

        AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion(soundID, nil, nil, { soundID, inClientData in
            let me = unsafeBitCast(inClientData, Sound.self)
            me.audioServicesPlaySystemSoundCompleted(soundID) -> Error: Thread 1: EXEC_BAD_ACCESS
        }, UnsafeMutablePointer(unsafeAddressOf(self)))
    }

    func audioServicesPlaySystemSoundCompleted(soundID: SystemSoundID) {
        print("Completion")
        isPlaying = false
        AudioServicesRemoveSystemSoundCompletion(soundID)
        AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(soundID)
    }
}
```

Error: Thread 1: EXEC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 2, address = xxx)

I really have no idea why I got this error. I debugged the code and the address of `me` is exactly same as the `self` passed in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems I need to retain the value of `self` like this and `unsafe` methods don't automatically retain the instance. Weird.

```
AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion(soundID, nil, nil, { (soundID, inClientData) -> Void in
    let me = Unmanaged<Sound>.fromOpaque(COpaquePointer(inClientData)).takeRetainedValue()
    me.isPlaying = false
}, UnsafeMutablePointer(Unmanaged.passRetained(self).toOpaque()))
```

Inspired by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30788165/304319), but instead of using `unretained` methods, I used the `retained` methods instead.