# Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UnsafeMutablePointer'

Tags: reachability, swift3

I'm trying to update Reachability.swift to swift 3.0 and I'm having trouble passing the Reachability instance to the call back function.

Here is my snippet:
* please note self = Reachability class

```
var context = SCNetworkReachabilityContext(version: 0, info: nil, retain: nil, release: nil, copyDescription: nil)

context.info = UnsafeMutablePointer(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque())
```

Where the compiler throws an error saying:

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<_>' with an
>   argument list of type '(UnsafeMutableRawPointer)'
>
> Pointer conversion restricted: use '.assumingMemoryBound(to:)' or
>   '.bindMemory(to:capacity:)' to view memory as a type.
>
> Overloads for 'UnsafeMutablePointer<_>' exist with these partially
>   matching parameter lists: (RawPointer), (OpaquePointer),
>   (OpaquePointer?), (UnsafeMutablePointer),
>   (UnsafeMutablePointer?)

What I understand I need to convert self which is of type `open class Reachability: NSObject` to an UnsafeMutablPointer but Im not sure how to proceed.

Comment: at the callback `func callback(reachability: SCNetworkReachability, flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags, info: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    print("--- callback")
    guard let info = info else { return }
    let reachability = Unmanaged<Reachability>.fromOpaque(info).takeUnretainedValue()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        reachability.reachabilityChanged()
    }
}`

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/d6uc8z8kij1zmmf/Reachability%20Swift%203.zip?dl=1

Comment: @LeoDabus thank you thats awesome!

Comment: Compare also http://stackoverflow.com/a/30788165/1187415, which was updated for Swift 3 some time ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the type of `info` property from [the latest reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/systemconfiguration/scnetworkreachabilitycontext/1514901-info):

> **Declaration**
>
> ```
> var info: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?
> ```

And the type of `toOpaque()` has become `UnsafeMutableRawPointer`.
(I couldn't have found an up-to-date Apple document, but you can check it easily in the Quick Help pane of Xcode.)

You have no need to convert:

```
    context.info = Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque()
```