# SCNetworkReachabilityCallBack? type conversion issue with Swift3.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, reachability

As Swift 2.3 to Swift 3.0 conversion raise many issue, I am trying to solve this issue but not getting solution so far.

> Cannot convert value of type '(SCNetworkReachability, flags:
>   SCNetworkReachabilityFlags, info: UnsafeMutablePointer) -> ()'
>   to expected argument type 'SCNetworkReachabilityCallBack?'

Here is my code :

```
func callback(_ reachability:SCNetworkReachability, flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags, info: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    let reachability = Unmanaged<Reachability>.fromOpaque(info).takeUnretainedValue()

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        reachability.reachabilityChanged(flags)
    }
}
```

In `startNotifier` function we are passing `callback`, but it generates error.

```
public func startNotifier() throws {

    guard !notifierRunning else { return }

    var context = SCNetworkReachabilityContext(version: 0, info: nil, retain: nil, release: nil, copyDescription: nil)
    context.info = UnsafeMutablePointer(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque())

    //THIS LINE GENERATES ERROR WARNING
    if !SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback(reachabilityRef!, callback, &context) {
        stopNotifier()
        throw ReachabilityError.unableToSetCallback
    }

    if !SCNetworkReachabilitySetDispatchQueue(reachabilityRef!, reachabilitySerialQueue) {
        stopNotifier()
        throw ReachabilityError.unableToSetDispatchQueue
    }

    // Perform an intial check
    reachabilitySerialQueue.async { () -> Void in
        let flags = self.reachabilityFlags
        self.reachabilityChanged(flags)
    }

    notifierRunning = true
}
```

This code generates error in above function.

```
    //THIS LINE GENERATES ERROR WARNING
    if !SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback(reachabilityRef!, callback, &context) {
        stopNotifier()
        throw ReachabilityError.unableToSetCallback
    }
```

[image]

I also go through this in depth post of [Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30786883/swift-2-unsafemutablepointervoid-to-object), but not getting solution.
Any help should be appreciable.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The referenced Q&A has code which compiles in the latest Xcode 8 beta 6, and even code for previous beta releases in the edit history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have something odd in Swift 3, always check [the latest reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/systemconfiguration/scnetworkreachabilitycallback):
(As for now, the latest reference is up to the latest Xcode 8, beta 6. If you are using beta 5 or older, the code below does not work.)

> ### Declaration
>
> ```
> typealias SCNetworkReachabilityCallBack = (
>     SCNetworkReachability,
>     SCNetworkReachabilityFlags,
>     UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) -> Void
> ```

The type of the last parameter of the call back has changed to `UnsafeMutableRawPointer?`.

So, you may need to change your `callback` to something like this:

```
func callback(_ reachability:SCNetworkReachability, flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags, info: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    let reachability = Unmanaged<Reachability>.fromOpaque(info!).takeUnretainedValue()

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        reachability.reachabilityChanged(flags)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not working, In Swift 3.0, declaration looks like this : `public typealias SCNetworkReachabilityCallBack = @convention(c) (SCNetworkReachability, SCNetworkReachabilityFlags, UnsafeMutablePointer<Swift.Void>?) -> Swift.Void`. So it complains `Use of undeclared type UnsafeMutableRawPointer`.

Comment: @technerd, aren't you using an older beta before beta 5?

Comment: I am using Xcode 8 , beta 4

Comment: @technerd: The "unsafe pointer" APIs changed several times in Swift 3. My answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/30788165/1187415 that you are referring to is updated for the latest Xcode 8 beta 6. If it does not work for you then it would be nice to leave a comment at my answer to that I can fix it.

Comment: @technerd, beta 6 was a big change for Swift. And I think GM version of Swift is very near to beta 6 than beta 4. I will add some note for who are using early betas, but I strongly recommend you to move to the latest beta and get ready for GM release.

Comment: @OOPer : So this answer will work with latest Xcode beta ?

Comment: @technerd, tested in Xcode 8 beta 6, I'm so sure.

Comment: @technerd: ... as does http://stackoverflow.com/a/30788165/1187415, which you already referred to. And versions for previous beta releases of Xcode 8 are in the edit history of that answer.

Comment: @MartinR  :I will check with latest Xcode beta, If there is any issue, i will update on your answer. Thanks to both of you.