# Using contextInfo, UnsafeRawPointer in UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum - Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UITableView`. When a cell is tapped, my app generates a relevant image. The image generation is done on a background thread, as some images make time a considerable time to render. Once an image has rendered, `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` is called on the main thread.

As any number of `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` tasks may be underway in any order, I need a way to track each task. I wish to store the `indexPath` of the selected cell, as `contextInfo`, passing it to `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum`.

When `image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:` is called, I need to get the indexPath out of contextInfo.

But, the vast majority of online examples of `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` pass nil for `contextInfo`.

I have read the official docs, the Swift 3 pointer migration guide, the header file, Objective-C code that uses bridging and casting, and a great many SO threads on the subject of `UnsafeMutableRawPointer`/`UnsafeRawPointer`.

End result: I am confused by the myriad options, and do not know whether I am missing something obvious, whether I should be performing `load()` on pointer data, should call `unsafeBitCast()`, or should sacrifice goats to the gods.

Or, reevaluate my career, and become a carpenter.

Q1. How can I store an instance of `IndexPath` in a form suitable for contextInfo?

Q2. Once `image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo` has been called, how do I form an `IndexPath` out of `contextInfo`, so as to get to my stored data? Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Finally, thankfully stumbled across a correct answer on SO:

[Swift 2 - UnsafeMutablePointer<Void> to object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30786883/swift-2-unsafemutablepointervoid-to-object)

A solution follows, based on the above answers. Any improvements or suggestions are welcomed.

For ease of use and debugging, I wrapped my data in a reference type:

```
class ImageWritingContext : NSObject
{
    var indexPath = IndexPath()
    // ...
}
```

The data needs to be held strongly. In this case, in an array property.

```
fileprivate var imageWritingContexts = [ImageWritingContext]()
```

When it comes time to draw, we stick the data in the wrapper and add the wrapper to the array.

```
let context = ImageWritingContext()
context.indexPath = indexPath
self.imageWritingContexts.insert(context, at: 0)
```

Now for the magic.

```
let contextRawPointer = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self.imageWritingContexts[0]).toOpaque())
```

Are we there yet, are we there yet?

```
let completionTarget: AnyObject = self
let completionSelector = #selector(self.image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:))

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image,
    completionTarget,
    completionSelector,
    contextRawPointer)
```

The callback:

```
func image(_ image: UIImage,
    didFinishSavingWithError error: Error?,
    contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer)
{
    // Perform error checking here.

    // Extract the data. Pop some valium first.
    let context: ImageWritingContext = Unmanaged<ImageWritingContext>
        .fromOpaque(contextInfo)
        .takeUnretainedValue()
    let indexPath = context.indexPath

    // Do something with the data.

    // Remember to remove the context from self.imageWritingContexts!
}
```