# Swift Selector in UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum not recognized, why?

Tags: ios, swift, selector

iOS API Function `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` takes a selector as one argment:

```
func UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(_ image: UIImage, 
                              _ completionTarget: Any?, 
                              _ completionSelector: Selector?, 
                              _ contextInfo: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?)
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/1619125-uiimagewritetosavedphotosalbum

However, in swift, when I call this function, the selector never gets recognized:

```
class Base {
   func save_image(img:UIImage) {
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, self, Selector("image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:"), nil)
        // I also tried this:
        // UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, self, #selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:))
    }

   @objc func image(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: Error?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
        print("Photo Saved Successfully")
    }
}

class Child:Base {
}

// This is how I call the save_image function:
let child = Child()
child.save_image()
```

As you can see, I tried constructing the selector from the signature, and from a string, but neither works. I always get this error in runtime:

```
'XXX.Child' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
Unrecognized selector ......
```

What is happening here? I am wondering if this is because swift doesn't see the method from the Child class, as the method is inherited from Base class?

How can I pass the selector successfully?

Relevant question I have read:

[@selector() in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007650/selector-in-swift)

Comment: What's your version of Swift? You should use `#selector()` if you use Swift 3 for instance. Also, here you have the solution (if you use Swift 3): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41093735/using-contextinfo-unsaferawpointer-in-uiimagewritetosavedphotosalbum-swift-3

Comment: @Larme Swift 3. I used `#selector()`, doesn't work either.

Answer (score 13):

methodSignatureForSelector is the NSObject's method.
So, You need to inherit the `NSObject` class.

```
class Base: NSObject {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Provide some guidance to your selector to help it find the right function:

```
class Base {
    func save_image(img:UIImage) {
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, self, #selector(Base.image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
    }

    @objc func image(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: Error?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
        print("Photo Saved Successfully")
    }
}

class Child:Base {
}

// This is how I call the save_image function:
let child = Child()
child.save_image()
```

Comment: @NeoWang did anything work for you? I had the same issue :/

Answer (score 3):

After all I have tried, I find that the crucial things are:

1. method signature must match(a lot of answers have covered that)
2. do not pass the parameters to the wrong positions, one of my failures is, I passed the `target` to the `contextInfo`
3. <strike>maybe</strike> in Swift only, the class that implements the the callback function, must be inherited from `NSObject`

Comment: SURELY -> in Swift only, the class that implements the callback function, must be inherited from NSObject

Comment: @ReimondHill yes, you are right, all objects in Objective-C are inherited from `NSObject` , only the objects in Swift have the choices

Comment: Step 3 fixed my problem and it was because I had a Swift class not extending from NSObject. However, I didn't think about adding @objc. Not sure if that will make a difference...